# Maximum value of a function with complicated partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

My problem:

> Find the maximum value $M$ of the function
>   $$f(x,y) = x^5 y^2 (6-x-y)^7$$
>   on the region $x\geq0, y\geq 0, x+y \leq 6.$

Solving the system of equations made of the partial derivatives (to find the critical points) is quite lengthy.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: consider the substitution $u = 6-x-y, v = x$ and work in these new coordinates

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: Thank you, and @Brian, thank you too, I will keep that in mind.